# Primitive sum in latex

Tags: math-operators

How to type a primitive sum (a summation sign with "*" sign at the top right corner) inside the equation?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In in-line math, `\sum^*` will suffice, but in a display, you have to suppress the "aboveness" of limits, so `\sum\nolimits^*` is needed.  (Not tested, and if there are also limits, things get more complicated.)

Comment: Thanks but when I add it then the limits of the sum creates a problem. Can you tell me when I have limit in the sum.

Comment: Try `\[
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\vphantom{\sum}}^*
\]` if it gives what you after ...

Comment: It is working. I need to write $\sum_{\chi(\bmod{q})}{\vphantom{\sum}}^*$, when I write it inside the equation the * sign is getting far away from the summation. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done with the `\sideset` command

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\psum}{\sideset{}{^*}\sum}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{q\le Q}\frac{q}{\varphi(q)}\psum_{\chi(\mathrm{mod}\ q)}
\]

\end{document}
```

The empty braces in `\sideset` are needed because `\sideset` allows for sub- and superscripts on the left side of the operator also.

Comment: +1 but allow me a cosmetic comment: in order to use `\sideset` we need `amsmath`, not `mathtools`. (Of course `mathtools` is always a good idea, but for clarity...)

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the primitive sum symbol, set with `\nolimits`, as a big-operator atom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\primsum{\mathop{\sum\nolimits^{*}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{q\le Q}\frac{q}{\varphi(q)}\primsum_{\chi(\mathrm{mod}\ q)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit

As requested by our grande dame, Barbara Beeton, here is a version that centers the sum symbol, without shifting it to the left because of the asterisk.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{suffix}

\newcommand\primsum{\mathop{\sum\nolimits^{*}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\primsum*{\mathop{\sum\nolimits^{\mathrlap{*}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q\le Q}\frac{q}{\varphi(q)} &\primsum_{\chi(\mathrm{mod}\ q)} \\
\sum_{q\le Q}\frac{q}{\varphi(q)} &\primsum*_{\chi(\mathrm{mod}\ q)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The sum looks like it's positioned a little to far to the left.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Okay, how about this new version?

Comment: Yes.  I like it.

Answer (score 5):

The difficult part is to keep the subscript centered under the summation symbol, not taking into account the asterisk. However, the width of the asterisk has to be taken into account for avoiding clash with the following material.

The assumption here is that only subscripts are used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\primsum}{e{_}}{%
  \mathchoice{\dprimsum{#1}}{\sum^{*}_{#1}}{\sum^{*}_{#1}}{\sum^{*}_{#1}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dprimsum}{m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\sum^{*}}{\makedprimsum{#1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makedprimsum}[1]{%
  % typeset without the *
  \sbox\z@{\scriptspace=0pt$\m@th\displaystyle\sum_{#1}$}%
  % typeset with the * on either side
  \sbox\tw@{\scriptspace=0pt$\m@th\displaystyle{}^{*}$$\m@th\displaystyle\sum\nolimits^*$}%
  % print the main symbol
  \mathop{{\sum}^{\mathrlap{*}}\kern-\scriptspace}_{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd\z@>\wd\tw@
    %  we can ignore the width of *
  \else
    \kern0.5\dimexpr\wd\tw@-\wd\z@\relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\primsum_{aaa}\Big| \\
\sum_{aaa}\Big| \\
\primsum_{aaaa}\Big| \\
\sum_{aaaa}\Big| \\
\primsum_{aaaaa}\Big| \\
\sum_{aaaaa}\Big| \\
\primsum_{aaaaaa}\Big| \\
\sum_{aaaaaa}\Big|
\end{gather*}

\begin{center}
$\primsum_{a}x\quad\scriptstyle\primsum_{a}x$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]